# Why is the rtcclient `getWorkitem()` for IBM RTC HTTP GET request returning incorrect response?

Tags: python, xml, rational-team-concert

I am trying to use the [rtcclient Python package](https://pypi.org/project/rtcclient/) to authenticate and retrieve work items from my IBM RTC board. Specifically my goal is to run this command without errors:

```py
myclient.getWorkitem("202007")
```

where 202007 is the id of an 'epic' ticket.

Whenever I try to run my program, I end up facing an XML parsing error, where rtcclient makes a GET request to a URL and expects to receive an XML data, but instead only shows HTML in the `resp.content`.

For example, if I start my Python shell and run these commands:

```
>>> from rtcclient.utils import setup_basic_logging
>>> from rtcclient import RTCClient
>>> setup_basic_logging()
>>> myclient = RTCClient("https://rtcus1.ta.company.com/ccm", "myUsername", "myPassword", ends_with_jazz=False) 

2022-02-22 16:55:55,605 DEBUG client.RTCClient: Get response from https://rtcus1.ta.company.com/ccm/authenticated/identity
2022-02-22 16:55:55,612 DEBUG urllib3.connectionpool: Starting new HTTPS connection (1): rtcus1.ta.company.com:443
2022-02-22 16:55:56,264 DEBUG urllib3.connectionpool: https://rtcus1.ta.company.com:443 "GET /ccm/authenticated/identity HTTP/1.1" 302 0
2022-02-22 16:55:56,288 ERROR client.RTCClient: Failed GET request at <https://rtcus1.ta.company.com/ccm/authenticated/identity> with response: b''
2022-02-22 16:55:56,290 DEBUG client.RTCClient: Get response from https://rtcus1.ta.company.com/ccm/authenticated/identity
2022-02-22 16:55:56,292 DEBUG urllib3.connectionpool: Starting new HTTPS connection (1): rtcus1.ta.company.com:443
2022-02-22 16:55:56,875 DEBUG urllib3.connectionpool: https://rtcus1.ta.company.com:443 "GET /ccm/authenticated/identity HTTP/1.1" 302 0
2022-02-22 16:55:56,886 ERROR client.RTCClient: Failed GET request at <https://rtcus1.ta.company.com/ccm/authenticated/identity> with response: b''

>>> myclient.getWorkitem("202007")
```

After executing `getWorkItem`, it will run this code around line 909 of the rtcclient/rtcclient/client.py file

```
resp = self.get(req_url, verify=False, proxies=self.proxies, headerss=self.headers)
```

where:

- `req_url="https://rtcus1.ta.company.com/ccm/oslc/workitems/202007"`
- `proxies =  None`
- `headers =  {'Content-Type': 'text/xml', 'Cookie': 'WASReqURL=https:///ccm/authenticated/identity; Path=/; Secure; HttpOnly; WASReqURL=https:///ccm/authenticated/identity; Path=/; Secure; HttpOnly', 'Accept': 'text/xml'}`

After the request completes, the value of `resp.content` is a long HTML string which contains 'Loading...' and '>Javascript is either disabled or not available in your Browser':

```
b'<!DOCTYPE html>\n<!--\n  \n-->\n\n<html >\n<head>\n<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">\n<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=10">\n<title></title>\n\n<lin...... ody>\n</html>\n'
```

But if I go to the `req_url` in my browser where I have logged in with the same credentials, I see valid XML data; this is the data I need rtcclient to fetch:

[image]

But instead, it fetches that HTML data which messes up the program and prevents me from fetching work items. Does anyone have a solution or know how I could make a request to my RTC XML URL in postman to fetch the XML data and verify it is possible to do so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check first if this was working with 0.6.0 (depending on your RTC version 6.x?; 7.x).

[`dixudx/rtcclient` issue 136](https://github.com/dixudx/rtcclient/issues/136) mentions:

> v0.7.0 has introduced a change on authentication, refer to [#133 for details](https://github.com/dixudx/rtcclient/pull/133) (and [issue 112](https://github.com/dixudx/rtcclient/issues/112)), which may be not compatible with older Rational Team Concert. From your issue, it seems to be true. Sorry for this.
>
> My suggestion is just sticking with older rtcclient version, such as `pip install rtcclient==0.6.0`.